# Message broker with dynamic queues

Tags: rabbitmq, messaging, task-queue

I have application that accepts data for updating products prices and I wondering how I can optimize it.

Data is received in some kind of queue ( rabbitMQ )

[image]

Few key notes:

- I can't change incoming data format ( data is received from third party )
- Updates must be performed in order from product perspective ( due attributes )
- Each of product CAN have additional attributes by which system can behave differently when updating prices internally

I was thinking about using some messaging system too to distribute processing something like that:

[image]

where :

Q1 is queue for handling only p1 product updates.
Q2 is queue for handling only p2 product updates.
and so on..

However I have found it is likely to be more anti-pattern: [Dynamic queue creation with RabbitMQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21265242/dynamic-queue-creation-with-rabbitmq)
For example seems with RabbitMQ it would be even quite hard to achieve since we need to have predefined queues in order to listen them.

The question is:

1) Should I use another pattern in case this is not valid and which pattern I should use
2) In case this pattern is valid is there some kind different messaging system that would allow distribute data by this pattern