# Dynamic RabbitMQ per user request Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, websocket, rabbitmq, queue

I have. I have a web application that processes video streams. Users can stream live video / or video file to Receiver Pods, and these Master Pods will spawn new Processing Pods, to handle each user request. It will also create a new queue to store these video frames, and the Processing Pods will read and process these video streams (bytes or frames) and stream back to the Receiver Pod and back to the user. When video live stream is done, the Processing pods should be destroyed. The protocol used for communication will be websocket.

Is this possible with RabbitMQ?

I came across this question, but it was asked almost a decade ago

[Dynamic queue creation with RabbitMQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21265242/dynamic-queue-creation-with-rabbitmq)

I am not sure now with Kubernetes, if this is feasible and/or a good idea